# List comprehension from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, series

I have a dataframe with dates, times and values

```
Date       Time Value
2017-01-05 1730 893
2017-01-05 1700 990
2017-01-05 1600 801
2017-02-01 1700 701
2017-02-01 1800 774
```

I want to build a list comprehension that takes date + time as a key to return specific values. So for example:

```
Date = 2017-01-05, Time = 1600 gives Value 801
Date = 2017-02-01, Time = 1800 gives Value 774
```

The following code sort of works - apart from the fact that I'm left with an ugly array type in my list:

```
valueList =[]

for d, t in df:
    valueList.append(df[(df['Date'] == d) & (df['Time'] == t)].Value.values)
```

But I'd really like to do is generate a list of selected values using a list comprehension.

Comment: You can do the following: 
`valueList = [ df[(df['Date'] == d) & (df['Time'] == t)].Value.values for d,t in df]`

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  If you want to query your dataframe, why do you need a list?

Comment: Could you just add expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate the problem. A list comprehension does not have keys, so you cannot use it for a mapping. You can, however, use a `pd.Series` or `dict` object.

You can simply create a series with your index as `['Date', 'Time']`:

```
s = df.set_index(['Date', 'Time'])['Value']

print(s.get(('2017-02-01', 1700)))
# 701
```

If you need a dictionary:

```
d = s.to_dict()
```

In either case, you can access a value given a date and time directly.

Comment: Thanks, good advice. I probably made a poor choice of language in the use of keys etc. Anyway, that solves the problem for me!